# Syntax error in formatting of decimals in python

Tags: python, format, syntax-error, decimal

failing please help

```
myRand = (('{0:0.3f}'.format(myRand)) random.random()* (1.001 - 1.501) +1.501)
print (myRand)
```

invalid syntax error?

Comment: you write only one `{ }`, so you can pass one parameter to `format()`, after that `random.random() ...` you have to remove it

Comment: Why do you think there isn't an error?

Comment: you have passed myRand in argument but you haven't declared yet.

Comment: The `syntax error` is because of `random.random() ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute `myRand` and format it in the same statement. Compute first, format afterwards:

```
>>> myRand = random.random() * (1.001 - 1.501) + 1.501   
>>> myRand = '{0:0.3f}'.format(myRand)
>>> myRand
'1.275'
```

If you *must* do it in one line then:

```
>>> myRand = '{0:0.3f}'.format(random.random() * (1.001 - 1.501) + 1.501)
```

though I wouldn't if I were you.

Comment: thanks i did try this but had my formatting wrong great answer